# Why cannot resolve DbContext in constructor of custom middleware?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, middleware

I have custom middleware. I tried constructor injection to inject my DbContext. But it does not work. The following does not work and gives the InvalidOperationException: Cannot resolve scoped service 'MyDbContext' from root provider;

```
private MyDbContext _context;    
public RequestResponseMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, MyDbContext context)
{
    _next = next;
    _context = context;
}
```

But when i use it in InvokeAsync method as a parameter it works. The following works

```
public Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, MyDbContext  _context)
{

}
```

Does anyone know the reason?

Comment: Should work if you register DbContext as transient.

Comment: [From docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2#service-lifetimes) `When using a scoped service in a middleware, inject the service into the Invoke or InvokeAsync method. Don't inject via constructor injection because it forces the service to behave like a singleton. For more information, see ASP.NET Core Middleware.`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`DbContext` are usually registered as scoped services.

> When using a scoped service in a middleware, inject the service into the `Invoke` or `InvokeAsync` method. **Don't inject via constructor injection because it forces the service to behave like a singleton**. For more information, see [ASP.NET Core Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/index?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

*Emphasis mine*

Reference [Dependency injection in ASP.NET Core: Scoped Service lifetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2#service-lifetimes)