# ASP.NET Core Web API, inject database context into exception handling

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection

I'm trying to write custom exception handling that would write error details into the database.

Right now (in the code I inherited) the DB context is injected into static class with extension method:

Startup.cs:

```
ExceptionMiddleware.ExceptionMiddlewareConstructor(app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IErrorLoggerService>());
```

ExceptionMiddleware.cs:

```
public static class ExceptionMiddleware
{
    private static IErrorLoggerService _service;
    public static void ExceptionMiddlewareConstructor(IErrorLoggerService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }
    public static void ConfigureExceptionHandler(this IApplicationBuilder app, ILog logger)
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler(appError =>
        {
            appError.Run(async context =>
            {
                if (context != null)
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

                    var requestString = "Query: " + context.Request.QueryString.Value;

                    if (context.Request.Method != "GET")
                    {
                        context.Request.Body.Position = 0;
                        using StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(context.Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8, true, 1024, true);
                        requestString += "Body" + await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                    }

                    var contextFeature = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
                    if (contextFeature != null)
                    {
                        var claims = context.User.Claims.ToList();

                        //Filter specific claim    
                        var email = claims.FirstOrDefault(x =>
                            x.Type.Equals("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress",
                                StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))?.Value;

                        if (contextFeature.Error.StackTrace != null)
                        {
                            var error = new ERROR
                            {
                                //assinging property values for DB entity
                            };

                            await _service.CreateAsync(error);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

ErrorLoggerService is a service that handles db write for ERROR entities, and has DbContext injected into constructor.

Obviously current code is not thread-safe because of the captured dependency to DbContext, but I'm not sure how to inject DbContext into exception handler properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you registed your dbcontext as a scoped service by default,

```
// If you didn't pass the parameter of servicelife time into the method,the lifetime would be scoped by default
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ZipTestContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("SomeDbContext") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'SomeDbContext' not found.")),ServiceLifetime.Scoped);
```

you could get the dbcontext from container as below:

```
var dbcontext = context.RequestServices.CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetService<SomeDbContext>();
```

And the case related may help:[Why cannot resolve DbContext in constructor of custom middleware?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56720233/why-cannot-resolve-dbcontext-in-constructor-of-custom-middleware)

Tried as below:

```
exceptionHandlerApp.Run(async context =>
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError;
        // using static System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames;
        context.Response.ContentType = Text.Plain;


        //var dbcontext = context.RequestServices.GetService<ZipTestContext>();
        var dbcontext = context.RequestServices.CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetService<ZipTestContext>();
        var somemodel = new SomeModel() { Description = "Description", Name = "SomeName" };
        dbcontext?.Add(somemodel);
        dbcontext?.SaveChangesAsync();

        await context.Response.WriteAsync("An exception was thrown.");

        var exceptionHandlerPathFeature =
            context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();

        if (exceptionHandlerPathFeature?.Error is FileNotFoundException)
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync(" The file was not found.");
        }

        if (exceptionHandlerPathFeature?.Path == "/")
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync(" Page: Home.");
        }
    });
});
```

You could see the different performance between

```
var dbcontext = context.RequestServices.GetService<ZipTestContext>();
            var dbcontext =
```

And

```
context.RequestServices.CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetService<ZipTestContext>();
```

Result1:

[image]

Result2:

[image]